# SaxParseException-Premature end of File

Tags: java, xml, io

```
        File xml = new File("C:/members.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xml);


        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("member");
```

Actually this problem parse(xml).I get the error message "Premature end of file" first record add xmlfile.I can't find the true solution.Pls help me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <members>
        <member id="0">
            <name>a</name>
            <surname>a</surname>
            <fatherName>a</fatherName>
            <age>0</age>
            <email>a@a.com</email>
            <username>a</username>
            <password>a</password>
        </member>
    </members>
```

Comment: Well show us a minimal but complete sample of  `members.xml` allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: your first tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is giving some error. I am not sure what it is but when I replaced that tag with my xml tag then it works fine.(though there is no change in my tag. Try manually typing the same tag.)

Comment: is your file ('members.xml') really encoded in UTF-8 like the XML Prolog states ? if the encoding defined in the xml prolog and the actual file encoding differ this might lead to such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your example - the following code runs without error:

```
public void test() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
            + "<members>"
            + "<member id=\"0\">"
            + "<name>a</name>"
            + "<surname>a</surname>"
            + "<fatherName>a</fatherName>"
            + "<age>0</age>"
            + "<email>a@a.com</email>"
            + "<username>a</username>"
            + "<password>a</password>"
            + "</member>"
            + "</members>";
    //File xml = new File("C:/members.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));

    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("member");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to open the xml file in webbrowse (firefox or chrome)
add see whether they report any error.

if you have linux you can do:

`xmllint members.xml`

this command tells whether the file is valid xml or not